# Python pandas 'reverse' split in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

i have a dataframe with a column called details that have this data :

130 m² - 3 Pièces - 2 Chambres - 2 Salles de bains - Bon état - 20-30 ans -

when i want to get the first data 130 i did this :

`df['superficie'] = df['details'].str.split('m²').str[0]`

its gives me 130 in a new column that called "superficie"

for the the seconde data i did this :

`df['nbPieces']= (df['details'].str.split('-').str[1].str.split('Pièces').str[0])`

it gives me 3 in a new column that called "nbPieces"

but my problème is if i want to get the 2 of the champbres and 2 of the salles de bains and the 20-30 near of "ans" , how can i do that, i need to add them to new columns (nbChambre , nbSalleDeBain, NbAnnee)

thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [regular expressions in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) for this kind of operations:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['details'] = ["130 m² - 3 Pièces - 2 Chambres - 2 Salles de bains - Bon état - 20-30 ans -"]

df['nb_chbr'] = df['details'].str.split(" - ").str[2].str.findall(r'\d+').str[0].astype('int64')

df['nb_sdb'] = df['details'].str.split(" - ").str[3].str.findall(r'\d+').str[0].astype('int64')

df['nb_annee'] = df['details'].str.split(" - ").str[5].str.findall(r'\d+').str[0].astype('int64')

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
details  nb_chbr  nb_sdb  nb_annee
0  130 m² - 3 Pièces - 2 Chambres - 2 Salles de b...        2       2        20
```

Moreover, I used `" - "` as a split string. It returns a better list in your case. And for the "Nombre d'années" case I simply took the first integer that appears in the list, I don't know if it suits you.

Finally there may be a problem in your dataframe, 2 chambres and 2 salles de bain should be a 4 pièces flat ^^

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast help , i really appreciate that , it works like a charm , but i don't know why if added the .astyp... at the end it gives me this error :

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_12688\2911626522.py in <module>
----> 1 df['nbChbr']  = df['details'].str.split(" - ").str[2].str.findall(r'\d+').str[0].astype('int64')

Comment: Do you have a clue on which ['details'] row it happens? This may be due to bad formatting of your dataframe. By the way, `.astype('int64')` is simply here so that you have integers in your column, it is not mandatory if you don't need to perform calculation on your dataframe